# NullInjectorError: No provider for MedicalDataComponent

Tags: angular, module, provider

I am including and component's html by using 
But getting an arror:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ClinicalInformationComponent -> 
MedicalDataComponent]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ClinicalInformationComponent -> 
MedicalDataComponent]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for MedicalDataComponent!
```

files are
bot.html

```
<app-information></app-information>
```

bot.nodule

```
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BotAnalysisComponent } from './bot.component';
   
    import { MedicalDataModule } from './medical-data.module';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        
        MedicalDataModule
      ],
      declarations: [BotAnalysisComponent,],
      providers: [ FileUploadModule, MedicalDataModule],
    })
    export class BotAnalysisModule { }
```

medica-data.module

```
  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
  
  import { MedicalDataComponent } from './medical-data.component';
  import { MedicalDataRoutingModule } from './medical-data-routing.module';
  import { ClinicalInformationComponent } from './clinical-information/clinical-information.component';


  // Angular 

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      NgxPaginationModule,
      
    ],
    declarations: [
    ClinicalInformationComponent,
    MedicalDataComponent
    ],
    providers:[],
    exports:[ClinicalInformationComponent]
  })
  export class MedicalDataModule { }
```

I removed some material and form libraries which was imported.

Comment: where you have injected `MedicalDataComponent`? Please add code

Comment: Updated Please see once

Comment: Before share. The above Modules and Components are not imported in the app.module.ts

Comment: Move `FileUploadModule, MedicalDataModule` modules to `imports` array of `BotAnalysisModule`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually the error was that, the MedicalDataComponent require provider from where its called in its constructor. I passed the MedicalDataComponent in the provider:[MedicalDataComponent] in the bot.module file and its working.